# Programming in C With Windows API: How To Draw A Command Button

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Well, I am building a college project in C. GUI has not been taught yet but I want my program to be better, so I am learning Windows API.

I am following this tutorial here: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/start.html and it is quite good.
It explains lot of things but I am not able to find one thing(even searched Google but everything is oriented towards C++ or C#):

How do I draw a command button inside the drawn window(which I have learned) and how to accept events for it?

Can you please answer or point me to a good page that explains how I can create a command button using ONLY Windows API and C. No C++ please.

Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: What you really need is Charles Petzold's book Programming Windows.

Comment: @David Well, thanks for suggestion. I have just dived into API and if I think it's good for me, I will get the book.

Comment: Just keep following the tutorial you found. http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/controls.html. I can vouch that it's an excellent tutorial.

Comment: @tenfour OK, I will continue with it and then go to the second one that NineFingers suggested. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](http://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/) is a tutorial I highly recommend on the Win32 API user interface functions. It's excellent. Roughly speaking, in your callback function (`LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )` you have several options you can catch:

```
switch(msg)  
{
    case WM_CREATE:
        break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        break;
    /* .. */
}
```

What you need to do on `WM_CREATE` is something like this:

```
HWND hWnd_button = CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Quit"),    
                 WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
                 20, 50, 80, 25,        
                 hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);
```

The reason I've stored the `HWND` of that button is that if you want to alter the button at a later date, you'll need that Handle as an argument for `SendMessage()`. Now, next up, catching a click. When the button is clicked, it sends `WM_COMMAND` to the parent window with the `HMENU` casted argument (1 in this case) in `wParam`. This works for every control you create (menus, checkboxes etc - if they post more complicated options they may be present in `lParam`). So:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == 1) {
        DestroyWindow();
        /* or SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE,0,0); see commments */
    }
    break;
```

Catches that particular option. Inside the `if` handles that button event.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that excellent tutorial. And great answer too!

Comment: @Ishan No problem. The Petzold book is a good one, I also recommend it, it covers a lot. However, for just getting going that tutorial is a great introduction to the basic stuff.

Comment: PostQuitMessage is not really the proper way to close a window, the button should send WM_CLOSE or if you don't have any WM_CLOSE handling (Abort if there are unsaved changes etc) you can call DestroyWindow, DestroyWindow ends up sending WM_DESTROY, there you handle all cleanup for the window and call PostQuitMessage

Comment: @Anders I know, but I was writing straight out of the tutorial since that was faster than finding the code where I've actually done this... I'll fix it though for completeness sake.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [`CreateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with class name `"BUTTON"`, style `BS_PUSHBUTTON` and parent window as your existing drawn window. The x and y coordinates select the top-left button position in the window. The window name is the text on the button. Also, remember to call `ShowWindow` on the returned handle.

edit: To accept events for it, first define an ID value like:

> `#define ID_MYBUTTON 1`

Then pass that into the menu-parameter of the CreateWindow call. In your main windows message proc you can now find message by testing for:

> `if(message == WM_COMMAND && HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED && LOWORD(wParam) == ID_MYBUTTON) { /* button was clicked */ }`

Comment: So I have to create a new window for a button? Well, that's something new. I am going to try it. Thanks for quick answer.